# How to use where method on an alias defined on a select method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

everyone. So I'm having trouble making this query.

I have this code:

```
obj = object.select("COALESCE(sum(stock.quantity), 0) as cnt")
```

and it returns

```
obj.first.cnt
# 0
```

And I want to filter the counts with

```
object.select("COALESCE(sum(stock.quantity), 0) as cnt").where(cnt: 0)
```

I couldn't make it to work. It returns a

```
<#Object::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x3fe455b3ad5c>
```

Comment: `count` is a built in function in SQL. Use another name like `as stock_quantity`.

Comment: @max Edited the code. My issue still remains. The alias doesn't seem to work in the where clause.

Comment: You've said it doesn't work, could you share how it fails? Does it throw an error? Does it return the wrong data? What's the expected output? What's the current output?

Comment: @thesecretmaster Yeah, so when I do `object.select("COALESCE(sum(stock.quantity), 0) as cnt").first.cnt` it returns 0 but when I add `object.select("COALESCE(sum(stock.quantity), 0) as cnt").where(cnt: 0)` it doesn't return the object with the count equal to 0".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `.where(cnt: 0)` will assume that cnt is a column on the table:

```
WHERE "objects"."cnt" = ?
```

AR doesn't actually know that cnt is an alias.

You can instead use a string literal to refer to the alias:

```
object.select("COALESCE(sum(stock.quantity), 0) as cnt")
      .where(Arel.sql("cnt = ?"), 0)
```

Comment: You can't use a where clause on an Aggregate function like `SUM` this should be moved to a `HAVING` clause.

Comment: @engineersmnky some databases do allow it, but you're very right in that the results may not be what you actually want.

Comment: Interesting I haven't come across any of these databases, do you mind enlightening me?

Comment: SQLite and I think MySQL for example will allow the query even if it's wildly ambiguous.

Comment: @engineersmnky Actually it seems like its just SQLite. Interesting that it has no problems with `SELECT COALESCE("stocks"."quantity", 0) AS c_count FROM "stocks" WHERE (c_count = 0)`.

Comment: SQLite is strange in general and allows a lot of queries that contradict SQL Standards. Like referencing column aliases in a where clause

Comment: Any solutions for doing it with Postgres?

Comment: Use GROUP and HAVING instead of where.